# Java Keytool error after importing certificate with Startup GPO, “keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException & Access Denied”

Tags: java, keystore, keytool, gpo

I'm trying to import a CA on java jre7 keystore with the following script

```
if exist "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\keytool.exe" -import -alias "name" -keystore "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\lib\security\cacerts" -file "%~dp0ca.pem" -storepass changeit -noprompt
```

When i launch the script without the "run as administrator" i have the following error "keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException & Access Denied"
When i launch the script with the "run as administrator" the importation work great

The issue is that i use this script with a Startup Gpo who deploy it on every desktop on the company, it should deploy the script with admin right but the importation don't work with the GPO

Could someone please help ?

Comment: Cross site duplicate of [Can I Deploy a batch file with Group Policy to run as administrator?](https://serverfault.com/questions/644801/can-i-deploy-a-batch-file-with-group-policy-to-run-as-administrator).

Comment: The GPO is already running under the context of Local System as a Startup script

Comment: On the system where you run the script as admin, have you checked if your policy is having some problem related to UAC (settings required for UAC to be minimal)?

Comment: The settings are the same for all desktop in the compagny, UAC settings are on default

Comment: BTW, this question doesn't belong here. You may get a better help on Server Fault as this is a GPO related problem, and has nothing to do with programming.